# Java BufferedImage: one image or many?

Tags: java, image, swing, bufferedimage

I'm working on a game, and I am using various tilesets. Suppose for example that my tileset is 25x25 (meaning each image is 25px wide by 25px high), and I have 16 images. I can either use one 100x100 image and use the BufferedImage#getSubimage method, or I can create 16 25x25 .png files. The first answer would save on time since I wouldn't need to create the 16 files required, but the second method would be clearer since I can name each of my files something obvious.

I'm mostly worried about performance; is it better to keep several small images in memory, or one large file?

Has anyone tried both methods? If so, which did you find worked best?

Comment: Considering that there is performance overhead in reading a File as well as decoding the image format, I'd suggest you'd finder it more efficient to read a single large file and use sub image to carve it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People generally go with spritesheets/tilesets as this cuts down on size and it's not really much a performance hit to just grab the image you need based on its position and size. For a 2D game with pixel graphics, performance isn't generally much of a concern anyway.